# i want do, on submit button do 2 form action

Tags: php, mysqli

i trying to do that when user click on submit button, currently i am define in action paypal link but i also  want it goes on update.php and follow update query, is it possible to onclick one submite button also goes paypal payment gateway page and also update.php page

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
            <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="demo-chai@gmail.com"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://ahigher.aiscor.com/">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="clear_cart">Clear Cart</a>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="pay via paypal">  
       </form>
```

Comment: I am not that familiar with PayPal's api, but you should probably post to your own server and make an api request to PayPal from there.

Comment: did you set ipn for Paypal? it will help you get data from PayPal after completed payment process and you can update it post data

Comment: why is this a mysqli question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think two actions are possible.
PayPal will return requested data back, you can receive that data in a file and then insert or update your database.

Here is a tutorial for PayPal integration [click here](https://phppot.com/php/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-php/)